# Is there a map for the feywild equivalent of Faerûn?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, campaign-settings, forgotten-realms, maps

It is stated somewhere between the books in D&D 4e that the Feywild is a lot like Toril when its about its geographical shape.

Even though, it isn't the same. And I'm looking for those small differences. The best way to be sure would be if I had a map, since my players wanna try to use the feywild as a shortcut and I don't wanna rule arbitrarily on this since I like to make them feel like in a sandbox game.

So, the quest is simple.
It there a map for the Feywild? It doesn't matter the edition it comes from (4e, 5e, f(x)²e, I don't care) as long as it is the feywild. I just need to see how different it is geographically.

Answer (score 4):

According to the blurb on [this site](http://www.mikeschley.com/128067/1267784/maps/fictional-world-regional-maps), there is a map of the Feywild created for the book Heroes of the Feywild. Look about 3/4 the way down the page, or search for the term Feywild. It says you can purchase a copy, or you can probably get the book and get it that way as well.

[image]

Comment: It's not from Toril it seems, but it's already helpful.

Comment: @DaviBraid - Just do a google image search for Feywild, that's where I sourced this, and there are dozens of maps available.